# How to setup this association in Factory Girl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

First time doing testing/using Factory Girl and I'm all confused.  I've got a model called Partnerships and it has a has_one relationship with another model called Schools.

Partnership Model:

```
class Partnership < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_one :school
end
```

School Model:

```
class School < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :name
   belongs_to :partnership
end
```

School Factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :school do
    name "Elementary School" 
  end
end
```

Partnership Factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :partnership do
    association :school

    factory :partnership_for_school do 
        after(:create) do |partnership|
            partnership.school FactoryGirl.build(:school)
        end
    end


  end

end
```

In my spec file, I tried to create a very simple test:

```
describe "Partnerships" do

    it "should be able to create a partnership with a school" do
        school_partnership = FactoryGirl.create(:partnership_for_school)
        school_partnership.school_id.should_not be_nil
    end



end
```

But when I run this test, I keep getting that the school_id in the partnership object is nil. I thought I built the school association in the partnership factory, but I'm going wrong somewhere.

Any ideas on where I went wrong?

**Update**

Here is the stack trace when I run the test:

```
Partnerships should be able to create a partnership with a school
 Failure/Error: school_partnership = FactoryGirl.create(:partnership_for_school)
 ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
   PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column schools.partnership_id does not exist
   LINE 1: SELECT  "schools".* FROM "schools"  WHERE "schools"."partner...
                                                     ^
   : SELECT  "schools".* FROM "schools"  WHERE "schools"."partnership_id" = 17 LIMIT 1
 # ./spec/factories/partnerships.rb:11:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
 # ./spec/requests/partnerships_spec.rb:8:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
 # -e:1:in `<main>'
```

**Update 2**

When I run rake db:test:prepare, I get this error:

```
 ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  zero-length delimited identifier       at or near """"
LINE 1: DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS ""
                            ^
: DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS ""
```

Here is my schema with the partnership and school tables:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20140812210757) do


 create_table "partnerships", :force => true do |t|
  t.integer  "school_id"
  t.datetime "created_at",      :null => false
  t.datetime "updated_at",      :null => false
 end

 create_table "schools", :force => true do |t|
   t.string   "name"
   t.datetime "created_at",          :null => false
   t.datetime "updated_at",          :null => false
 end

end
```

Comment: It seems like there might be something wrong with your database schema. Verify that your test database is using the schema by running `rake db:test:prepare`, then try again. If that didn't work, update your question with the `db/schema.rb`.

Comment: Alright so I ran rake db:test:prepare and I got a strange error (see above). I also copied my schema for the partnerships and schools tables. Let me know if there is anything else that is relevant. I should note that I'm using rails 3, if that matters.

Comment: So I just got it to pass!  But the way I did it was to switch the has_one and belongs_to relationship in my partnership and school models.  I'm new to rails so I guess I just did that incorrectly. Thanks so much for the help.

Comment: Ah yes. I missed that one too. Glad to hear it's solved!